# Can any substance directly damage our certain functions of brain?

Tags: brain, toxicity, toxins, brain-damage

As we know, that if our brain (thinking, memory, logics, etc.) functioning is damaged, there would be other symptoms associated with it.

Let me clarify,

EXAMPLE 1: suppose a person had COPD due to high carbon dioxide levels in his home. Now, he would be unconscious, headache. And due to this COPD, he'd also face short term memory loss.

EXAMPLE 2: An experiment found that a person had held his breath for >6 minutes. He became unconscious, and after he was treated at hospital, he was having trouble recalling past events.

In the above two examples, there is a slight damage in memory part of the brain **with symptoms**.

Now, coming to my question, I had to ask that has anyone known any such compound, or any such chemical which could damage (without any symptoms) - certain parts of our brain (for example: higher order thinking skills, calculation, logical thinking, etc.)?

Comment: if I should ask this in Biology SE, let me know. If some more info is needed, let me know

Comment: It would be off topic in Biology just as it is here. We cannot help you self-diagnose poisoning and brain damage by food, water, or drugs.

Comment: No, its not about poisoning or brain damage. I just want to ask if symptoms are accompanied with damage in - logical, memory, or any such functional part of brain. Or any drug will directly affect them? @CareyGregory